# Find distance between X and Y of groups with fixed start point

Tags: python, distance, geopandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

This is the data to calculate distances

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'survey_data.csv',
                   delimiter=',')

start = pd.read_csv(r'start_points.csv',
                   delimiter=',')
print(data)
print(start)

data['Trans'] = data['Trans'].str.upper()
```

get only transects used from start points file

```
unique = data['Trans'].unique()
start = pd.DataFrame(start.loc[start['Trans'].isin(unique)])
```

choose columns to be used

```
start['Dist'] = 0.0
cols = ['Y','X', 'Elev']
```

Set Trans as the index coulmn

```
a = data.set_index('Trans')[cols]
b = start.set_index('Trans')[cols]
```

use Pythagorean theorem for distance. This bit of code is where I'm getting error message

```
a['Dist'] = (a.subtract(b, level=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**(1/2)
```

Stacking start points and calculated points and sorting

```
r = pd.concat([a.reset_index(), start]).sort_values(by = ['Trans', 'Dist'])


print(r)
```

file used for data

```
  Trans      Y      X  Elev
0     TR9  101.5  101.5   5.5
1     TR9  111.0  111.0   8.0
2     TR9  121.0  121.0   6.0
3     TR9  131.0  131.0   7.0
4     TR9  141.0  141.0   4.0
5    TR10  101.0  201.0   2.0
6    TR10  111.0  211.0   6.0
7    TR10  121.0  221.0   5.0
8    TR10  131.0  231.0   7.0
9    TR10  141.0  241.0   8.0
10  GRAND  101.0  301.0   5.0
11  GRAND  111.0  311.0   6.0
12  GRAND  121.0  321.0   7.0
13  GRAND  131.0  331.0   9.0
14  GRAND  141.0  341.0   5.0
15   TR11  101.0  401.0   4.0
16   TR11  111.5  411.5   6.0
17   TR11  121.0  421.0   8.0
18   TR11  131.0  431.0   4.0
19   TR11  141.0  441.0   2.0
```

file used for start points

```
   Trans      Y      X   Elev
0    TR9   99.5   99.5    4.0
1   TR10   99.0  199.5    3.2
2  GRAND   99.0  299.5    6.5
3   TR11   99.0  399.5    8.2
4   TR99  999.0  999.0  999.9
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I am using python 3 but am rather new to it. I can only figure out how to make separate dataframes for each transect (a b and c) and then calculate the distance from there. But ideally i would like to match the Transect ID of starting point and calculate the distance to subsequent poins in dataframe for each transect

Comment: I've been trying .loc based on transect name and .groupby transect name. I realize I am probably not describing my problem very well. I'll try and post some code tomorrow.

Comment: @RyanS Welcome to SO, please read [ask] on how to improve your question. For starters please add the datasets in code blocks instead of an image/link of image. Also, please clearly describe the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question and adding your attempt. Please find my solution that should solve your issue below. You can utilize the broadcasting capabilities that pandas offers over the index values to solve this.

Comment: I see you have changed the data quite a bit. Please find my updated answer with the new dataset example that you provide in question.

Comment: Do mark the solution as solved if this solves your question at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Akshay Sehgal!

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT -** Since you updated your question and changed the data, column names, and rows, here is the solution to the latest edited question. Detailed explanation below.

```
start['Dist'] = 0.0  #Adding Dist column to s

#getting X, Y and setting index to "Trans"
cols = ['X','Y', 'Elev']
a = data.set_index('Trans')[cols]
b = start.set_index('Trans')[cols]
b = b.loc[a.index.unique()]  #<--- to ensure that same trans elements exist in both

#Calculating broadcasted distance (by index)
#D = √((Long1-Long2)²+(Lat1-Lat2)²+(Alt1-Alt2)²)
a['Dist'] = list((a.subtract(b, level=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**(1/2))

#Stacking start points and calculated points and sorting 
r = pd.concat([a.reset_index(), start]).sort_values(by = ['Trans', 'Dist'])
print(r)
```

```
    Trans      X      Y   Elev       Dist
2   GRAND  299.5   99.0    6.5   0.000000
10  GRAND  301.0  101.0    5.0   4.887740
11  GRAND  311.0  111.0    6.0  17.466826
12  GRAND  321.0  121.0    7.0  30.761827
13  GRAND  331.0  131.0    9.0  45.098670
14  GRAND  341.0  141.0    5.0  59.369100
1    TR10  199.5   99.0    3.2   0.000000
5    TR10  201.0  101.0    2.0   2.773085
6    TR10  211.0  111.0    6.0  16.854970
7    TR10  221.0  121.0    5.0  30.813796
8    TR10  231.0  131.0    7.0  45.063178
9    TR10  241.0  141.0    8.0  59.239261
3    TR11  399.5   99.0    8.2   0.000000
15   TR11  401.0  101.0    4.0   3.201562
16   TR11  411.5  111.5    6.0  16.748134
17   TR11  421.0  121.0    8.0  30.471298
18   TR11  431.0  131.0    4.0  44.648628
19   TR11  441.0  141.0    2.0  58.689863
0     TR9   99.5   99.5    4.0   0.000000
0     TR9  101.5  101.5    5.5   2.915476
1     TR9  111.0  111.0    8.0  16.628289
2     TR9  121.0  121.0    6.0  30.765240
3     TR9  131.0  131.0    7.0  44.972214
4     TR9  141.0  141.0    4.0  59.063525
4    TR99  999.0  999.0  999.9   0.000000
```

**Details -**

1. Set the `Transect` to index for each of the dataframe and keep only the `Northing`, `Easting` and `Elev` columns
2. Use `df.subtract` between the 2 dataframes and set `level=0`. What this does is that it will use `broadcasting` to subtract all the rows with the same index. So, 2 rows of first and 1 row of second with index=`A` will be subtracted with broadcasting to give 2 rows. Similarly others for each feature.
3. Once you have the subtracted dataframe, just take `square`, sum it over `axis=1` and then take `square root` to get your distance.

> D=√((Long1-Long2)²+(Lat1-Lat2)²+(Alt1-Alt2)²)

4. Finally set this series to the `['dist']` column of the original dataset.

Comment: Akshay Sehgal, when I use this code on a csv file that is in the same format i keep getting the error " raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" I'm guessing that there is an error in my  step                                                                                                                                    
 cols = ['Y','X', 'Elev']

a = data.set_index('Trans')[cols]
b = start.set_index('Trans')[cols]

Comment: when you load the data, is 'Trans' already an index?

Comment: I have an elevation column so I'm using the first code you sent me. Trans is not already an index when i import

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the error

Comment: I can't figure out how to add a screenshot to the comments. I will buy you a "coffee" though for your troubles.

Comment: oh thats kind of you. just add the screenshot to the question. ill see it there

Comment: I added the screenshots. I think i discovered the issue. When my 'Trans' are labelled A B and C it works fine but if i give them a name such as ['Trans1', 'Trans2'] i get an error message.

Comment: Hey in the last statement, you using `by = ('Transact', 'Dist')` and it should be `'Trans'`

Comment: last line should be `r = pd.concat([a.reset_index(), start]).sort_values(by = ['Trans', 'Dist'])`

Comment: the error is occurring with this line of code if my trans have A# labels but works if just alphabietical                                                                                                                  a['Dist'] = (a.subtract(b, level=0)**2).sum(axis=1)**(1/2)

Comment: also can you print a and b? before the line with error

Comment: I am unable to replicate the error at my end. can you please post the complete data on the question? the ones I see in the screenshot? Just print `data` and `start` and copy and paste the whole tables in a code block in the question. I will only be able to figure out whats wrong if i can replicate the same error.

Comment: Ah ok, i get it. The issue is that the calculated series has 21 elements while the original a has 20. this is because there is an extra `trans` value that only exists in b but not in a

Comment: Updating my answer now.

Comment: Changed the series to a list AND also added a double check to remove elements in b that dont exist in a.

Comment: That did work. Thanks again. So the thing that got it working was list correct?

Comment: Not just that, but also `b = b.loc[a.index.unique()]`. this would have caused issues as well. The list is there because the series already had an index that was different than the original index in a. Thats why when you were setting it to `a['dist']` it said it cant reindex.